# Popup window when checkbox checked in asp.net

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I would like to show a `confirmation Box` with the message when the user check the `CheckBox`.
So i have a `GridView` and there is a column for `CheckBoxes`. 
So whenever user check the `CheckBox` i would like to show a confirmation box and when user click cancel on that box i would like to uncheck that `CheckBox`.
when user press OK then i would like to fire a standard asp.net `CheckBox_CheckedChanged` where i am doing some database work.
I dont know how to do that in `javascript` or `Jquery`. 
I found it on google where there is only one `CheckBox` and you can use the `ID` and using the `Jquery` you can show the popup.
 BUT i have a GridView and there are lots of `CheckBoxes` for each row.

Please suggest me some working example or Code.

Thanks

******* *EDITS* ***********
here is the code i have got so far.

```
$('#gvOrders').click(function () {
        var checked = $(this).is(':checked');
        if (checked) {
            document.getElementById("confirm_value").value = "Yes";
            if (!confirm('Are you sure you want to mark this order as received?')) {
                $(this).removeAttr('checked');
            }
        }
        else {
            document.getElementById("confirm_value").value = "No";
            if (!confirm('Are you sure you want to mark this order as  not received?')) {
                $(this).removeAttr('checked');
        }
    });
```

This is not working so far when `CheckBox` checked. I am not sure what i am doing wrong here.

*** *HTML FOR GRIDVIEW* *********

```
  <asp:GridView ID="gvOrders" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" CssClass="gvClickCollectOrders"
    DataKeyNames="ac_OrderId" OnRowDataBound="gvOrders_RowDataBound" AllowPaging="true">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="ac_OrderId" Visible="false" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="ac_OrderNumber" HeaderText="Order No" DataFormatString="WWW{0}" />
         <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Order Date">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <%# GetOrderDate(AlwaysConvert.ToInt(Eval("ac_OrderId"))) %>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Customer Name">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <%# Eval("CustomerFirstName") %>&nbsp;<%# Eval("CustomerLastName") %>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Received In Store">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:CheckBox ID="cbIsReceived" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" Checked='<%# Eval("IsReceived") %>'
                    OnCheckedChanged="cbIsReceived_CheckedChanged"/>
                    <asp:Label ID="receivedDateText" Text="" runat="server"></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Collected By Customer">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:CheckBox ID="cbIsCollected" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" Checked='<%# Eval("IsCollected") %>'
                    OnCheckedChanged="cbIsCollected_CheckedChanged" />
                    <asp:Label ID="collectedDateText" Text="" runat="server"></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
    <EmptyDataTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="emptyGrid" runat="server" Text="there are no Click and Collect orders placed for the selected store."
            CssClass="emptyGridMessage"></asp:Label>
    </EmptyDataTemplate>
</asp:GridView>
```

Comment: put your html of your gridview

Comment: see my edits. I have put my code but its not working

Comment: `gvOrders` is your grid-view id?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Using jQuery*

Assign some class to your gridview checkbox and bind the event on that class.

```
<asp:CheckBox id="chkChoice" runat="server" class="some-class" ></asp:CheckBox>    

$('.some-class').click(function () {
    var checked = $(this).is(':checked');
    if (checked) {
        document.getElementById("confirm_value").value = "Yes";
        if (!confirm('Are you sure you want to mark this order as received?')) {
            $(this).removeAttr('checked');
        }
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById("confirm_value").value = "No";
        if (!confirm('Are you sure you want to mark this order as  not received?')) {
            $(this).removeAttr('checked');

        }
    }
    //return someVariableHoldTrueOrFalseForPostBack
    //return true of false from here.
});
```

*Using javascript*

You can bind the javascript event on check box and it will be applied to all generated checkboxes of each row of grid automatically.

```
<asp:CheckBox id="chkChoice" runat="server" OnClientClick="return yourFunction(this)" ></asp:CheckBox>

function yourFunction(source)
{
     return confirm("your message"); 
}
```

Comment: Returning false from javascript will do that which will be returned by confirm.

Comment: You have to return true or false from the javascript function. True for postback and false for not postback.

Answer (score 1):

use the following code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $("#gvOrders input:checkbox").click(function(e) {
    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
        var m= confirm("your message");
        if(m !=true)
          {
              $(this).removeAttr('checked');
              e.preventDefault(); 
           }     
       });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

To show a pop on checkbox checked

```
1.Create a div and design a popup as per your wish in your aspx page.
2.check if the checkbox is checked or not.
3.If it is checked then call the div as popup using its id.
```

**c# Code:**

```
if(checkedbox.checked==true)
{
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "Call my function", "showpopup();", true); 
}
```

**Script:**

```
  function showpopup() {
    $("#popup").fadeIn('slow');
    }
```

where #popup is the id of the popup div which u have created.